# Failed to pass parameter to stored procedure from Excel macro

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which I cannot edit. To execute in SQL Server, I have to pass a parameter, which is mandatory. If I use '1', the procedure will run in print mode and actual procedure will be run for '0'. I wrote below code which is executed without errors and log is captured that stored procedure is run successfully but in print mode.

Please tell me the change that needs to be done to pass parameter '0'

```
Sub RunProc()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Queries")
strServerNAme = CStr(objSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value)
strDatabase = CStr(objSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value)
strProcName = CStr(objSheet.Cells(6, 2).Value)
' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure

strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=" & strServerNAme & "; Database=" & strDatabase & " ;"
con.Open strConnection
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adBoolean, adParamInput, False)

cmd.CommandText = strProcName
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us the stored procedure's header (the `CREATE PROC ...` stuff before the body of the procedure).

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209(v=vs.85).aspx), CreateParameter takes 5 args: `CreateParameter (Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value)`. It looks like you're missing one so you may be passing False as the Size when you mean for False to be the value

Comment: Actual way: `CreateParameter (Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value)`. It looks like im missing one. So after change.. It wotked

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say to change this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adBoolean, adParamInput, False)
```

to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@paramName", adBoolean, adParamInput, False)
```

using the actual parameter name.

Comment: above provided suggestion didnot help.

Comment: @Lakshmi Then we'll need to see the stored procedure to go any further.

Comment: I cannot show the stored procedures here.. Is there any other option to solve this issue?

Comment: No.  We are not psychic, so if you cannot show us the call interface, then we cannot possibly tell what's going wrong in your attempts to call it.

Comment: `CreateParameter (Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value)`. It looks like im missed one out of 5 fields. So after change.. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Due to security reasons I couldn't giv u store proc which was written by development team. I hope u understand..